# Oracle 11g enterprise db to be imported into Oracle 11g express without error using imp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have a database in Oracle, it has been made with the database "CMS" and with the username and password of "CMS" and "CMS". 
The problem is its dump has been taken by Oracle 11g enterprise, i want to import it into Oracle 11g express for development purpose. I dont know how to do it if i use imp command and i want to import it into same CMS schema with the same username and password. I created an account CMS on it first, but when i try to import it into that user using imp command, it says no permission. 
I am trying my best to explain the problem, but it is bit complex to explain. Please guide as i am very new in oracle.

Comment: Can you post the exact command-line that was used to generate the export and the exact command-line that is being used to run the import?  Can you post the actual error stack?  Presumably, there is some sort of `ORA-xxxxx` error number, an error message, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use Express Edition?  The [developer license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) allows you to use Enterprise Edition for free for development.  There's usually no need for the crippleware version if you're already paying for the real version.